# how create autocomplete with datalist

Tags: javascript, html

i'm try to create a autocomplete with datalist html this is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="options" name="options" list="list_option">
<datalist id="list_option">
  <option value="1">Op1</option>
  <option value="2">Op2</option>
</datalist>
<input type="button" onclick="data($('#options').val());" value="getId">
<script>
function data(term){
alert(term);
}
</script>
```

the list show correct the problem is if i select a item from my datalist on the input show the value, dont the name...
and how i can get this value(id).. please any suggest..thanks

Comment: You could use jQuery autocomplete it is more simpler to use.here is the  link https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: yeah of course but have error $(...).autocomplete is dont functio

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: $(...).autocomplete is dont function

Comment: This will only show if your js file not properly included before your js code. You can check the code by clicking the view source link below of this page https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

> *"...dont the name... and how i can get this value(id)."*

I have no idea what you mean...or how it relates to autocomplete.

The following Demo will run callback function `getData()` when the [**`change`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event is fired on `#options`. The console (not alarm because it's irritating) will log two items:

1. Text Box Value

Run callback function `getID()` when the `click` event is fired on `:button`. The console will log:

2. Text Box ID
3. Data List ID

As for autocomplete behavior, you just add the **[`autocomplete` attribute](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/autocomplete-attribute/)** to the text box tag or not, because it's on by default. To test it, just type in a letter.

`.autocomplete()` is not a built-in method of JavaScript or jQuery. You need to load [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) as Mr. Noyon commented or a [plugin](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20autocomplete%20plugin&oq=jquery%20autocomplete%20plugin&gs_l).

BTW, never use an onclick attribute event handler when you have jQuery loaded. That's like pushing a car instead of driving it.

---

### Demo

```js
$('#options').on('change', getData);
$(':button').on('click', getID);

function getID(event) {
  var textID = $('#options')[0].id;
  var listID = $('#list')[0].id;
  console.log('Text Box ID: #' + textID);
  console.log('List ID: #' + listID);
}

function getData(event) {
  var val = this.value;
  console.log('Text Box Value: ' + val);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="options" name="options" list="list" autocomplete>
<datalist id="list">
  <option value='wallet'>wallet</option>
  <option value='hair'>hair</option>
  <option value='coasters'>coasters</option>
  <option value='book'>book</option>
  <option value='clay pot'>clay pot</option>
  <option value='twezzers'>twezzers</option>
</datalist>

<input type='button' value='getID'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How to get `input`  element fill with the nearest value on the data list, e.g. if I type  `h` the input will fill with `hair` word automatically .

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? Just tested it with Chrome and Firefox Win11 and it still works as per your description.

Comment: I'm using both `opera and chrome`  on Arch Linux. Here is my reply on other comment,, I only saw it on Windows accounting application, in the input box if I start typing ap it's will automatically complete it to apple inside the box , even if the options available continue only the whole word sweet apple it will select it to me if I just start trying app . I can create my own script, but it will take from me days to finish. BTW google had better datalist usability, if if highlight it with arrow key it will be filled into the input, while by default you need to hit enter to get it selected

Comment: Do you want behavior so it actually fills the word in before you finish? So if your intention was to type in "apply", then once "app" was typed in, it will enter "apple" in the input you are typing into? I think that behavior was useful in an accounting app because the context was narrow in possibilities. If used in a typical environment that would be bad UX.

Comment: if the `datalist` contains both words `apply apple` it will select the word according to alphabet order , if I'm sure I want `apply` instead of `apple` I could continue typing on my own, since the letters I typed myself are not highlighted ( _still in white background_ ) while the word suggested by the app, are highlighted with light blue and white text . It's a clever system, I'm sure they got it from `.Net` plugin or `Delphi` add-ons since i don't know what they build that system with.

Comment: So if a `datalist` happens to contain similar words it will hold of until the user types past the identical parts then it must decide which word it should pick for the user, then regardless of what the user was typing, it will enter "y" or "e"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245154/discussion-between-salem-and-zer00ne).